# JasperReports Default Font

Tags: java, client-server, jasper-reports

I have a JasperReport template (generated on the Server) with a Styled Textfield (RTF). The Content of this field is User generated, and so it can contain all Fonts installed at the Clients PC (call it Font X). If I generate now a Report on the Server, there is no Font X, so I want to replace all unknown Fonts to Font Y.

But all I get is an error, that the font is not found. The feature ([net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font)) to turn off Font Checks in general isn't desired, because I want the Fonts of the jrxml checked.

Is there a way to set a default font (without the modification of the Jasper Source)? (I have found some points already at JRStyledText or JRTextUtil.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use **`net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name`** property.

Or you can use the *`default style`*.

```xml
<style name="Base" isDefault="true" ...>
```

For more details you can read this [article](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fonts), the *`Default Fonts and Inheritance`* section.

***UPDATED:***

The quote from ***JasperReports Ultimate Guide***:

> We strongly encourage people to use in their reports only fonts that
>   are provided in font extensions. This is the only way to be sure that
>   the fonts will be available to the application when the reports are
>   executed at runtime. Using system fonts always brings the risk that
>   the reports do not work properly when deployed on a machine that does
>   not have those fonts installed.

Comment: jeah I'v already set this property, but i still have to disable ignore.missing.font...

Is there a way to ignore missing fonts only on specific fields?

Comment: @itshorty And what is your question? I thought it was: `is there a way to set a default font` ...

Comment: Yeah, but keep ignore.missing.font enabled...
There is only one field where fonts are not always available, so I want turn off font checking only for this fields.

Comment: And what about setting style for this element?

Comment: then I get an JRFontNotFoundException if a User used a unknown Font. But i want use all known fonts.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a font that is 100% installed on all users PC and on the server?